# ios - crash when returning from a remote server call and evaluating the error object

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection

I have this code after a remote call is made and

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {   
         NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
         NSString *responseError = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:error encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
         ...
```

And on the last line sometimes the code crashes.  I can not reproduce the crash, but one guess I have is that if the error object is nil then the crash happens, am I right?  Should I check if error is not nil first?

This is the error from crashalytics:

```
Reason:
-[NSURLError bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22b215d0
```

which does not support my guess of why the error happens.  Any idea why this crash happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an `NSError` object to the `initWithData:` method (that expects an `NSData` object. Most likely you are getting a compiler warning. Never ignore compiler warnings. Your code should compile clean.

To get the error message use the proper `NSError` method such as `localizedDescription`.

```
NSString *responseError = [error localizedDescription];
```

Comment: thanks you :) and yes I did have a compiler warning. Will clean those up now in other places too :)